# Find average of non-zero numbers preceding a zero?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column with numbers and I want to calculate the average of all non-zero numbers preceding a zero. E.g.: If I have a column called Units, I would expect the Average column to get populated if I write the formula.

```
Units Average
32     32 
33     32
31     32
 0      0
 0      0
 1      2
 2      2
 3      2
 0      0
 1      1.5
 2      1.5
```

Is there a way in excel to perform this using formula?

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way of doing this with existing worksheet functions. However, if you are prepared to accept a userdefined worksheet function then this function could be applied directy to your data range and would give you the desired result.

Comment: "...all non-zero numbers preceding a zero" - what do you mean?  Will some kind of `AverageIf()` formula work?

Comment: @cars10 user defined function would definitely be accepted.

Comment: Yes I think you need to say what results you expect, it's pretty ambiguous as it stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite simply with formulas if you just use a single helper column, as follows [assumes that your data is in column A starting at A2, your helper column is in column B starting at B2, and your results will be in column C starting at C2]:

Helper column [Put in B2 and drag down]:

```
=IF(A2=0, "", IF(A1=0,MAX(B$1:B1)+1,B1))
```

This creates a unique identifier that iterates upwards by 1 each time there is a non-zero value in column A, and the value in the row above is 0. ie: a group of rows will all have the same ID number until a row with a 0 appears - then the next block of numbers will have an ID number which is 1 higher than the last group. Note that B2 will need to be hardcoded to 1, or else make A1 equal to 0.

Results column in [C2 and drag down]:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,B:B,B2)
```

This picks up the average in column A, for all rows matching the identifier created in the helper column.

Comment: I did experiment with an array formula and it can be done, but I think this is a more sensible approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as simple and short as I would have whished for but, nonetheless, here it is:

```
Option Base 1
Function myavg(r As Range)
  Dim i%, i0%, j%, n%, ia, a, oa()
  ia = r
  n = UBound(ia, 1)     ' get number of rows
  ReDim oa(n, 1)        ' prepare an output array with same no of rows
  a = 0:  i0 = 0        ' a:  accumulator summing up values
                        ' i0: position of last 0 value found
  For i = 1 To n        ' go through all input rows
    If (ia(i, 1) = 0) Then ' current value is zero:
      oa(i, 1) = 0         ' set output value to 0
     If i > i0 + 1 Then
      a = a / (i - i0 - 1)    ' calculate average value of previous group
      For j = i0 + 1 To i - 1 ' and assign it to output array
        oa(j, 1) = a
      Next j
      a = 0                ' reset the accumulator
     End If
     i0 = i
    Else
     a = a + ia(i, 1)      ' add to accumulator
    End If
  Next i

  If i > i0 + 1 Then       ' do average calculation for last group
   a = a / (i - i0 - 1)    ' if it was not ended with a 0 value
   For j = i0 + 1 To i - 1
       oa(j, 1) = a
   Next j
  End If

  myavg = oa
End Function
```

The user-defined worksheet function works as a matrix-function. This means you will have to select the target range (i.e. `C2:C12)`), enter the function like `=myavg(B2:B12)` and then press `<shift><ctrl><return>`. This will apply the function as a matrix function.

[image: sample worksheet table with matrix function entered]

The function will then appear to be surrounded by curly brackets `{}` like

[image: matrix function appearance]

Answer (score 1):

Just to show a completely different approach:

```
Public Function special_average(rng As Range)
  If rng.Value = 0 Then special_average = "": Exit Function
  Dim i As Long, lower_rng As Range, str As String
  Set lower_rng = rng

  If rng.Row > 1 Then str = rng.Offset(-1, 0).Text
  While str <> "0" And Len(str) > 0 And IsNumeric(str) And rng.Row > 1
    Set rng = rng.Offset(-1, 0)
    str = rng.Offset(-1, 0).Text
  Wend

  If lower_rng.Row < Rows.Count Then str = lower_rng.Offset(1, 0).Text Else str = ""
  While str <> "0" And Len(str) > 0 And IsNumeric(str) And lower_rng.Row < Rows.Count
    Set lower_rng = lower_rng.Offset(1, 0)
    str = lower_rng.Offset(1, 0).Text
  Wend

  special_average = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng.Parent.Range(rng, lower_rng))
End Function
```

In this case you just need to input one single cell. It will automatically go up and down to get the range to average. So for `B5` you just need `=special_average(A5)`.

Still, I would use the answer of *Grade 'Eh' Bacon*. It will be fast and also work if macros are disabled.

**EDIT:** To show a different approach to the formula way (without a helper column), you could put in `B2` and then copy down:

```
=IF(A2=0,"",IF(ISNUMBER(B1)*(B1<>0),B1,IFERROR(AVERAGE(OFFSET(A2,0,0, MATCH(0,A2:A1000,0)-1)),AVERAGE(A2:A1000))))
```

The downside is, that you need to set a max range (999 Rows in this example, which can be extended if necessary)